# how to wait until data from server is loaded

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have written simple app and have one problem with it.

I have mysql server and want to get data from it and display it on the screen of my phone.

I have a button on my android app, when i push it -> it should download the data and display it on screen, but my app want to display this data immidietly and loading it from server take a while so my app crash (beacuse data is still not ready).

I would be greatful for any solutions!

Regards
Mike

Comment: Can you please share your code and also crash log?

Comment: It's likely running on the UI thread which cannot tolerate long delays or an ANR exception occurs - there are straightforward solutions to this - simply post the button callback code you are using and advice can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is because your UI thread is blocked for more than 10 seconds.

Use AsyncTask calls instead.
For reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

When you want to retrieve data and display it, I would recommend that you take a look at [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data#0) for example. With this you can add an observer that will notify your app that the data is downloaded and can be displayed. Your code inside the observer won't be executed before the data is loaded.

```
// Create a LiveData object
val data = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()

// Here you should use your code to retrieve from where you want it and add it to the variable 'data'
data.value = X

// Observe your data
data.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) { retrievedData : List<String> -> 
// The code you add in the observer here will be executed when your data is loaded. The variable 'retrievedData' will contain that data.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to read data in pages if your app crash because of data is too big.

You can provide the first page to your application, and give the user the option to paginate through all available data on your server.